# Time cost analysis of trees

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree, time-complexity

I am having trouble calculating the time analysis of for the following algorithm on any arbitrary tree of size N.

Question is:

Consider the following algorithm,
which makes the following assumptions. x and y are the roots of two binary
trees, Tx and Ty. Left(z) is a pointer to the left child of node z in either
tree, and Right(z) points to the right child. If the node doesn't have a
left or right child, the pointer returns \NIL". Each node z also has a eld
Size(z) which returns the number of nodes in the sub-tree rooted at z.
Size(NIL) is defined to be 0. The algorithm SameTree(x; y) returns a
boolean answer that says whether or not the trees rooted at x and y are
the same if you ignore the difference between left and right pointers.

1. Program: SameTree(x,y: Nodes): Boolean;
2. IF Size(x) 6= Size(y) THEN return False; halt.
3. IF x = NIL THEN return T rue; halt.
4. IF (SameTree(Left(x); Left(y)) AND SameTree(Right(x); Right(y)))
   OR (SameTree(Right(x); Left(y)) AND SameTree(Left(x); Right(y)))
   THEN return T rue; halt.
5. Return False; halt

Give the time analysis to run the above algorithm on any arbitrary tree of size N. I got O(nlog2^3) for dense graphs and O(n) for less dense graphs. Am I right? Can someone help me determine the time costs please?

Answer (score 0):

Well let's use the Master principle. We shell consider the worst case where line 4 checks the condition before the OR and then checks the condition after it on EACH recursive call.
We will also simplify it by assuming the binaries trees are less or more balanced (has almost the same amount of nodes in each son of each node in the tree).
You have:

T(n) = 4*T(n/2)+2.

Look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem to understand what I will do next:
We have case 1 from the Master theorem.

log in base 2 of 4 is 2. so the correct answer is O(n^2). This is the analysis for the General Case. If you wish a more precise analysis, you need to tell us much more on the odds for your tree to be balanced, unbalanced and what is the chance of it built in such a way that line 4 will be activating both conditions in each recursive call.
Average cases are much more complicated.